# How to convert pandas float64 type to NUMERIC Bigquery type?

Tags: pandas, google-bigquery, pyarrow

I have a panda dataframe df:

```
<bound method NDFrame.head of                  DAT_RUN          DAT_FORECAST LIB_SOURCE  MES_LONGITUDE  MES_LATITUDE  MES_TEMPERATURE  MES_HUMIDITE  MES_PLUIE  MES_VITESSE_VENT  MES_U_WIND  MES_V_WIND
0   2022-03-29T00:00:00Z  2022-03-29T01:00:00Z    gfs_025          43.50          3.75        11.994824          72.0        0.0          2.653137   -2.402910   -1.124792
1   2022-03-29T00:00:00Z  2022-03-29T01:00:00Z    gfs_025          43.50          4.00        13.094824          74.3        0.0          2.976434   -2.972910   -0.144792
2   2022-03-29T00:00:00Z  2022-03-29T01:00:00Z    gfs_025          43.50          4.25        12.594824          75.3        0.0          3.128418   -2.702910    1.575208
3   2022-03-29T00:00:00Z  2022-03-29T01:00:00Z    gfs_025          43.50          4.50        12.094824          75.5        0.0          3.183418   -2.342910    2.155208
```

I convert DAT_RUN and DAT_FORECAST columns to datetime format :

```
df["DAT_RUN"]           = pd.to_datetime(df['DAT_RUN'],      format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ") # previously "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
df["DAT_FORECAST"]      = pd.to_datetime(df['DAT_FORECAST'], format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")

df.dtypes:

DAT_RUN             datetime64[ns]
DAT_FORECAST        datetime64[ns]
LIB_SOURCE                  object
MES_LONGITUDE              float64
MES_LATITUDE               float64
MES_TEMPERATURE            float64
MES_HUMIDITE               float64
MES_PLUIE                  float64
MES_VITESSE_VENT           float64
MES_U_WIND                 float64
MES_V_WIND                 float64
```

I use bigquery.Client().load_table_from_dataframe() function to insert data into Bigquery table which numeric columns have NUMERIC bigquery table.

It returns this error :

```
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Got bytestring of length 8 (expected 16)
```

I tried to fix it with :

```
df["MES_LONGITUDE"]     = df["MES_LONGITUDE"].astype(str).map(decimal.Decimal)
```

But no more.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to provide a scheme during the `load_table_from_dataframe()` function call to specify only the columns that can't be automatically inferred to get the NUMERIC type with your _MES_LONGITUDE_ column for example?

Comment: Yes thanks. My problem is when Pyarrow transform decimal data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to work around this issue with a [decimal.Context](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Context), hope it helps:

```py
import decimal

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "MES_HUMIDITE": np.array([2.653137, 2.976434, 3.128418, 3.183418]),
        "MES_PLUIE": np.array([-2.402910, -2.972910, -2.702910, -2.342910]),
    },
    dtype="float",
)
```

We check data type declaration:

```py
df.dtypes
# MES_HUMIDITE    float64
# MES_PLUIE       float64
# dtype: object
```

Initialize `Context` to 7 digits, because it is the precision in those columns, you can create multiple `Context` if you need different precision values for each column:

```py
context = decimal.Context(prec=7)
df["MES_HUMIDITE"] = df["MES_HUMIDITE"].apply(context.create_decimal_from_float)
df["MES_PLUIE"] = df["MES_PLUIE"].apply(context.create_decimal_from_float)
```

Now, each item is a Decimal object:

```py
df["MES_HUMIDITE"][0]
# Decimal('2.653137')
```

Types have changed and Pandas stores Decimals as objects, as I guess is not a native data format:

```py
df.dtypes
# MES_HUMIDITE    object
# MES_PLUIE       object
# dtype: object
```

```py
table_id = "test_dataset.test"
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("MES_HUMIDITE", "NUMERIC"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("MES_PLUIE", "NUMERIC"),
    ],
    write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE",
)

client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json("/path_to_key.json")
job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, table_id, job_config=job_config)
job.result()
```

However, [decimal types](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#decimal_types) are generally recommended for financial calculations and, although I do not know your exact case and usage, you are probably safe using `FLOAT64`, at least for [latitude and longitude](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#st_geogpoint).